# Is there a way to reverse 'revoke USB debugging authorizations' on Android

Tags: android, adb

I clicked on this under Developer Options on my Galaxy S5. The phone was causing issues during debugging so I thought clicking it might refresh the USB debugging but now I get an odd error that says 'Could not find device interface.' Does anyone know a way to reverse this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the device drivers required for your mobile is not installed in your computer. Please Try again after installing proper device drivers.

You can use tools like mobogenie (http://upload.mobogenie.com/mu/release/Mobogenie_Setup_3.3.7_10002.exe)
to connect your mobile in USB debugging mode. This will download and install drivers automatically and set up the connection

Comment: Did you find any device when typing adb devices

Comment: So it looks like it works after 10-15 min of doing adb kill-server and unplugging my device over and over again :(